# Does launcher works in android without mediaserver?

Tags: android, android-build, android-custom-attributes

Hi Iam trying to build android without media server and I faced problems in getting the launcher on the output.
I want to confirm whether we can work with the launcher without media server or not?
Though I know I can't play audio in it I just want to get that.
Any suggestions please?